# Is it possible to make oauth 2.0 requests using background page of chrome extensions?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, oauth-2.0, google-api-client

I have javascript code running in the background page of my chrome extension which calls Google api. The code below essentially requests for oAuth2 token.

```
function init(){
gapi.client.setApiKey(apiKey);
console.log("Initializing...");
gapi.auth.init(function() { setTimeout(authenticate,100)});
}
function authenticate(){
console.log("Initialized. Now AUthenticating");
gapi.auth.authorize({client_id: clientId, scope: scopes, immediate: false},api);    
}
```

The auth window opens as expected, however after user logs in and permits my app, the page merely freezes. The callback (api()) is never made and I dont receive a token. Is it because I'm calling it from a background page and the auth window has no way of sending a response back?

If yes, what is the workaround/ solution?

If so, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Boris Smus's  OAuth 2.0 Library for Chrome Extension](http://smus.com/oauth2-chrome-extensions/). It works great in my extension.

The reason why you cannot use OAuth2.0 in chrome extension:

> Chrome extensions can't directly use the OAuth 2.0 server-side or
>   client-side flows because they live at chrome-extension:// URLs